# Using Objects in Powershell to do command

Tags: azure, powershell

What im trying to do is the following:
Im getting a list of all VM`s that have some set values such as being in use and NOT having Azure Benefits turned on.

What i have is that i made a tiny script to get all machines within an subscription and select on the basis mentioned above.

What i want to do with that output is do the command Update-azureVM in bulk.
Could someone help me with this ? do i need to export the values to an excel and use that sheet to do a bulk `update-AzureVM`

here is the code that i have setup at the moment:

```
$returnObj = @()
$VMs=Get-AzVm -status
foreach ($VM in $VMs)

{
$obj = New-Object psobject -Property @{
    "VmSize" = $VM.HardwareProfile.VmSize;
    "VmName" = $vm.Name;
    "PowerState" = $vm.PowerState;
    "License_Type" = $vm.LicenseType;
     }

$returnObj += $obj | select VmSize, VmName, PowerState, License_Type 
}
$returnObj  |

Where-Object{$_.PowerState -ne "VM deallocated"} |
Where-Object{$_.License_Type -ne "Windows_Server"} | 
Where-Object{$_.License_Type -ne "Windows_Client"} | 

Export-Csv C:\temp\freek.csv
```

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Your `foreach` is missing an opening curly bracket. According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/update-azvm?view=azps-3.4.0#parameters) there is no `-Name` parameter for cmdlet `Update-AzVM`. There is no need for the backtick or the semi-colons.

Comment: You sir are correct, i made a mistake pasting the code. i have corrected this.

What im trying to do is [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/hybrid-use-benefit-licensing#powershell-1) but just in bulk using the object $VM.name to use in the Update-AzureVM command.

Comment: I cannot see what the problem is, you just need to update the VM in the `foreach` loop with the condition. So what is the problem that blocks you?